# Show Span if image src i'ts broken or missing

Tags: css, next.js

Hello I am trying to show a logo in next.js, my idea is to show a Span if the logo is not available and if it is it hides it.

```
<div className='brand'>
  <Link href="#">
    <img src="#" alt="UnSet" />
    <span>UnSet</span>
  </Link>
</div>
```

I tried this and it hides the image, now I want to achieve that if the image is empty it shows the span content and if not it shows the image.

```
.brand a img[src]{
  display: none;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some css and a simple JavaScript function to accomplish this.

Setup the CSS using a sibling selector:

```css
.brand span {
  display: none;
}
.brand img.unset {
  display: none;
}
.brand img.unset + span {
  display: block;
}
```

Then add this to the image objects.

```js
let images = document.querySelectorAll(".brand img");
for (i of images) {
  i.onerror = () => {
    this.classList.Add("unset");
    this.onerror = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should `import Image from 'next/image'`.

[Reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

Then,

```
<div className='brand'>
   <Link href="#">
      <Image src="#" alt="UnSet" unsized />
   </Link>
</div>
```